# How to make Thunderbird remember proxy password?

Tags: windows-xp, thunderbird

How to make Thunderbird3 remember proxy password?
Now I have to re-enter it every time I start TB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thread [Thunderbird won't remember web proxy passwords](http://getsatisfaction.com/mozilla_messaging/topics/thunderbird_wont_remember_web_proxy_passwords) gives the famous answer of :

> That is by design

However, the advice given further-on is to use the add-on [FoxyProxy](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/foxyproxy-standard/) as a solution to the problem.